# How does matchmaking work in Play mode?

Tags: hearthstone

How does Hearthstone match you with opponents in Play mode, for both Ranked and Unranked? Does your record in Ranked affect matchmaking in Unranked (and vice-versa)?

Comment: I'm guessing about the same as happens in SC2 given that they have the same devs...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Play_mode:

> **Casual**
>
> Matchmaking in Casual mode is determined by [matchmaking rating](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Matchmaking_rating), aiming to match the player against an opponent of comparable skill, with wins and losses affecting future opponent selection.
>
> **Ranked**
>
> There are 25 regular ranks, and an extra rank, 'Legend' above that. Each rank has its own medal and title, with ranks 2-25 named after minions from the game. All players start at rank 25: Angry Chicken. Players of ranks 1-25 will be matched in battle against players of similar rank, while players of Legend rank will be matched against other players of Legend rank, according to their [matchmaking rating](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Matchmaking_rating). Note that ranks are numbered in diminishing order: the smaller the number, the higher the rank.